# Loading JW Player in a "lightbox"

Tags: jquery, lightbox, jwplayer

I asked a specific question regarding an implementation of FancyBox version here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221253/loading-jw-player-inside-of-fancybox)

For *this* question, though, I am looking for any recommendations for the following scenario:

- A link is clicked and a lightbox is triggered in modal view
- JW Player is loaded inside the lightbox

I am running jQuery 1.6 and JW Player 5.8.

I've tried quite a few different light boxes, without success. I got close with Fancybox, but no prize yet.

Any suggestions for a lightbox that you know can accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Did you get any luck on this ..

Answer (score -3):

Try PrettyPopin, it's a Lightbox i used for my videos that pops up when clicked. go to this website http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com